# Idea ignores entire build directory

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle

I'm using Idea with Gradle plugin. Also I'm using antlr which generated Java source files into `build/generated-src/antlr/main`. Idea correctly adds that folder as a source root, but it also marks an entire build directory as an excluded directory. This prevents Idea from parsing those generated sources. I can manually remove `build` directory from excluded (and add to excluded everything under `build` except `build/generated-src`). This works but only until I reimport gradle project (and I need to do that after any change in `build.gradle`.

So the question is: can I ask Idea not to mark `build` directory after gradle reimport action?

Probably another option is to move `generated-src` directory from `build` directory, but I don't want to go that way.

Comment: Are you using the latest version of Idea?

Comment: Yes, latest release: 15.0.4.

Comment: You might consider using the Gradle idea plugin and generating the IntelliJ project. You'd then need to add configuration that adds build/everything_else as excluded.